# Django tests generate CommandError: x has a relation with model y, which has either not been installed or is abstract

Tags: python, django

I have the following error when I run tests that import one of my django apps which is called 'polls',

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
vote.vote: 'polls' has a relation with model polls.Vote, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
vote.vote: 'questions' has an m2m relation with model polls.Questions, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

The structure of the polls app models is not polls/models.py but is,

```
polls/
  models/
    __init__.py
    polls.py
    polls_stuff.py
```

where in polls.py/polls_stuff.py I have my models defined like so,

```
class Polls(models.Model):
    # fields...
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'polls'
```

(In the polls/models/**__*init*__**.py I import all the model classes)

It seems that the django test command has problems when the models are organized in their own directory as opposed to having models defined in a models.py file, which is the main runs file. However, I get CommandErrors by running tests in the polls app or tests that import the polls models. But regular app usage is perfectly smooth..

Anyone know how I can get around this and keep my models dir as is w/o refactoring my model definitions into one large models.py file...

Note: I'm using django 1.6 & python 3..